# Android Studio Failing to Store Arguments as Part of Fragment Bundle

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I've been wracking my brain for the greater part of the weekend, trying to solve an issue related to Android Studio. The assignment is to create a list fragment that will update when the user clicks buttons in the overhead bar, but despite my best efforts only one of the fragments actually displays (and it's the same no matter which button the user clicks). I've narrowed it down to the point where I'm fairly certain the problem has to do with the constructor's handling of bundles, but I'm not sure where the error is. Here's the related code:

```
public static ItemFragment newInstance(String title, int position) {
    ItemFragment fragment = new ItemFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1,title);
    args.putInt(ARG_PARAM2,position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

And later on, the call to getArguments():

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setRetainInstance(true);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mTitle=getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mPosition=getArguments().getInt(ARG_PARAM2);
        getActivity().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

      if (mPosition == 0) {
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, listItems));
    } else if (mPosition == 1) {
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, newGoalItems));
    } else if (mPosition == 2) {
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, markProgressItems));
    } else if (mPosition == 3) {
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, settingsItems));
    }
}
```

This is the related code in MainActivity:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_list) {
        list=ItemFragment.newInstance("List", 0);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.list_frame, new ItemFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
    else if (id==R.id.action_newGoal) {
        newGoal=ItemFragment.newInstance("New Goal", 1);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.list_frame, new ItemFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
    else if (id==R.id.action_markProgress)  {
        markProgress=ItemFragment.newInstance("Mark Progress", 2);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.list_frame, new ItemFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
    else if (id==R.id.action_settings)    {
        settings=ItemFragment.newInstance("Settings", 3);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.list_frame, new ItemFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I know from testing that the code simply crashes through the if statement above. What I don't know is why... It looks to me like there should be some values in getArguments that prevent it from returning null.

Comment: your code looks correct to me.. where do you called your getArguments()?

Comment: What do the method `getArguments` look like?

Comment: There's not enough code here to discern any problem.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by what the method getArguments look like... Should there be an implementation somewhere? Also, the only calls to getArguments() are the ones above.

Comment: I think what Handrata specifically meant is in what lifecycle method are you calling get arguments(onCreate, onResume, etc)? Also how/where are you calling newInstance()?

Comment: It's in the fragment's onCreate() method... I'm calling it from the MainActivity, in the onOptionsItemSelected() method.

Comment: add the code where you are launching the ItemFragment.

Comment: how about moving your `getArguments` process to `onCreateView()` on `onActivityCreated()` instead of `onCreate()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out! So the issue was that during the process of loading the fragments into the frame (the third section of code), the professor gave us a line of code that instantiated a new fragment instead of using the one that we'd just created a few lines above. I simply replaced

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.list_frame, new ItemFragment());
```

with

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.list_frame, list);
```

and now everything runs. Thanks for all the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Write this piece of code in fragments onCreate method() it will work

```
if (getArguments() != null) {
    mTitle=getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
    mPosition=getArguments().getInt(ARG_PARAM2);
    getActivity().setTitle(mTitle);
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any <fragment> tag in  your xml, Because onCreate() of the Fragment will be called first rather than calling in Java code, thus not setting the arguments.Try removing fragment tag from xml

Comment: There's no fragment tag in the XML that I can find... I think it's in this Java file because when I manually set the variable it adjusts fine; it's only setting it dynamically based on list selection that causes a problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Fragment newInstance(String title, int position) {
    Fragment fragment = new ItemFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1,title);
    args.putInt(ARG_PARAM2,position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

Change this line  ItemFragment fragment = new ItemFragment(); to this Fragment fragment = new ItemFragment(); and all your code is perfect.

Comment: I tried this, but it causes an issue with the line return fragment;

Comment: then change the return type of the method newInstance instead of ItemFragment use only Fragment.please check my updated solution.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to read the arguments in your Fragment's constructor. The context will not be established yet in the constructor, so you should be reading from the bundle in the onCreate() method.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain the situation well... The reading is set to occur in the onCreate() method already. I've added a larger portion of the code if that helps

Comment: Everything you are doing looks good to me. Have you tried commenting out the "setRetainInstance(true);" to see if that is affecting anything?